# SVGs stop animating when I scroll away and return

Tags: animation, svg

I have some animated SVGs on a [site I am developing](https://dev.vollrathmanufacturing.com/custom-home), and when I first scroll down to them (search for 'Appliances'), they are animated (it's a looping animation). However, if I scroll back up, then down, they are no longer animated, though sometimes, instead, a few remain animated and the others don't. This is only happening in Chrome, it doesn't happen when I test it in Opera. There really isn't anything custom to how the SVGs are embedded. Here is one:

`<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1neEAzubJI5AV4ohYjLKrfm6ROMyvaIBQ">`

I'm using a google drive link as I am developing, production will use links from a DAM. Sounds like it's a bug in Chrome (though in another site that has animated SVGs this doesn't happen, and I tested using one of the SVGs that is freezing in that site and no errors occurred) but maybe there's a workaround?

I expected the animation to continue uninterrupted no matter where I scrolled. They stop if I scroll away, then back.